# How do I open access database in C# using a file path from a command line argument?

Tags: c#, file, command-line, path

I need to specify the file path of an access db as a command line argument and pass it to my C# program, which will open and perform operation on it.

In the Command Prompt I type `F:\\count` which I should able to access using args[0], but I get `Invalid value for key 'data source'` exception.

When I put the same path in the code as `string path = "F:\\count"` then it works.

Please tell me what I'm doing wrong! I'm lost.

Here is my code:

```
namespace CountProjectPages
{
   public class CountProjectPages
   {
   private static OleDbConnection myConnection;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            string path = args[0];
            AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetData("DataDirectory",path);

            myConnection = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.JET.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\\test.mdb;Jet OLEDB:Database Password=aaa");
                string myScalarQuery = "SELECT COUNT (Content.Page) from Content";
                OleDbCommand myCommand = new OleDbCommand(myScalarQuery, myConnection);
                myConnection.Open();
                int total = (Int32)myCommand.ExecuteScalar();
                Console.WriteLine(total); 

                Console.WriteLine("DataSource: {0}",myConnection.DataSource);

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Ex: " + ex);
        }
        finally
        {
            myConnection.Close();
        } 

    }

   }
}
```

Comment: are you espcaing the \ in your input when you read it from args?

Comment: Try removing the ` \\ ` between the |DataDirectory| and `test.mdb`. Did this help?

Comment: It works when I remove  ` \\ ` between the |DataDirectory| and test.mdb

Comment: And the command line argument shoul be F:\count   (NOT F:\\count)

Comment: One more question: do you think that it's possible to pass the file name (e.g. test.mdb) as a command line argument too? If yes, how?

Comment: `var connectionString = String.Format("Provider=Microsoft.JET.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source={0};Jet OLEDB:Database Password=aaa", arg[0]);` just replace any part using this technique

Answer (score 0):

In response to your question

> do you think that it's possible to pass the file name (e.g. test.mdb) as a command line argument too?

[How to use command-line switches in Microsoft Access](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/209207)

Answer (score 0):

Check this code:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        string dbPath = null;
        if (args.Length > 0)
        {
            dbPath = args[0];
            string connectionString = "PROVIDER=MICROSOFT.JET.OLEDB.4.0;DATA SOURCE=" + dbPath + ";";
            using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
            {
                conn.Open();

                //TODO: handle other db commands...
            }
        }
    }
```

Make sure that command argument is passed as complete or relative path to mdb file using quotes like this: "f:\some directory\MyDataBase.mdb"